# GCOV Cross Profiling: __gcov_flush() does not flush coverage data for shared libraries

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

I am trying to get code coverage for an arm based embedded system. Using x86 for cross compilation.So basically, I have a cross profiling question.

For the application I want to generate code coverage data, I have defined a signal handler inside which I call `__gcov_flush()` to flush code coverage data to .gcda files. I am sending SIGUSR1 to the application. The application uses multiple .so files where bulk of the code and logic is implemented.

When I send the signal to the process, the .gcda files for just the application get created/updated. The .gcda files for the .so's are not created/updated at all.

Is there a way to make `__gcov_flush()` flush all the coverage data for the .so's that the application is using?

I dont want to force the application to `exit()` because that would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do. I need to be able to dump coverage data for the application and the .so it uses at runtime.
Please help!!

Using ARM GCC v4.5.1.

This is what I have done so far to generate code coverage data:

I have defined the following options for GCC in the Master makefile:
`CFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`
`LDFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`

I am also exporting `GCOV_PREFIX` and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP` as global environment variables on the target system to force the .gcda files to be created in a specific path. This is working.

My only problem is the .gcda files for the .so's not getting created/update when `__gcov_flush()` is called from the application.

Answer (score 5):

This question got answered on GCC mailing list.
TLDR: One needs to add a handler inside every shared library used, that will dump the coverage data. Then these handlers need to be called.

Detailed answer from [the mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-06/msg00135.html) follows.

#### Question from the mailing list

> *On Fri, 19 Jun 2015, Utpal Patel wrote:*
>
> I am trying to get code coverage for an arm based embedded system.
>   Using x86 for cross compilation.So basically, I have a cross profiling
>   question.
>
> For the application I want to generate code coverage data, I have
>   defined a signal handler inside which I call __gcov_flush() to flush
>   code coverage data to .gcda files. I am sending SIGUSR1 to the
>   application. The application uses multiple .so files where bulk of the
>   code and logic is implemented.
>
> When I send the signal to the process, the .gcda files for just the
>   application get created/updated. The .gcda files for the .so's are not
>   created/updated at all.
>
> Is there a way to make __gcov_flush() flush all the coverage data for
>   the .so's that the application is using?
>
> I dont want to force the application to exit() because that would
>   defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do. I need to be able to
>   dump coverage data for the application and the .so it uses at runtime.
>   Please help!!

#### Answer from the mailing list

> When you compiled your application with `-fprofile-arcs
>   -ftest-coverage`  only the application was instrumented (conceptually a 64bit counters in  each basic block of the apps minimum spaning
>   tree) and those counters  are what `__gcov_flush()` is dumping.
>
> So if you want profiling infos from libraries you need to compile the
>   library for profiling as gcov is a static instrumentation and there is
>   no way to get infos from a `.so` without that it was compiled for
>   profiling just like your application. If the application is compiled
>   for profiling then its data  will be dumped when you call
>   `__gcov_flush()` but since you can not send  signals to a library to
>   call some handler you would need to install some other mechanism in
>   the library e.g. brute force put a
>
> ```
> int libdump(void) {
>         __gcov_flush();                                                         
> }
> ```
>
> into the library and call that from your application signal handler
>   just like you called `__gcov_flush();` now.
>
> This is from a trivial library that just provides an open call that is
>   a wrapper to libc open and the libdump function
>
> ```
>     2:   77:int libdump(void) {
>     2:   78:        __gcov_flush();
>     1:   79:        return 0;
>     -:   80:}
>     -:   81:/* we now can get code coverage of the library */
>   145:   82:int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode) {
>   145:   83:        return __open(pathname, flags, mode);
>     -:   84:}
> ```
>
> the library is compiled with
>
> ```
> gcc -fPIC -Wall -g -O2 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -shared -o libgctest.so.0 libgc.c
> ```
>
> the application has the `libdump()` in the signal handler
>
> ```
> int libdump(void);
>
> void gc_handler(int signum)
> {
>         printf("received signal\n");
>         __gcov_flush(); /* dump coverage data on receiving SIGUSR1 */
>         libdump();      /* and dump library converage data */
> }
> ```
>
> and is compiled with
>
> ```
> gcc -O2 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage hello.c -o hello -lgctest
>  `kill -10 <PIDOF application>` will now dump the gcda of both application and library.
> ```
>
> HTH hofrat
>
> ps: I have no clue why the count of the return 0 line in the
>   libhandler does
>       not have a count of 2 as well....